# How can I simulate pasting in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For my application all that I want it to do is move the mouse to copy something from clipboard, move the mouse to text edit, and than paste it in there. I have everything working except the paste. How could I simulate paste in cocoa application? By paste I am referring to command+v on my macbook pro. Thank you.

This is what I have tried however all it does is ends up typing "v" into text edit. I don't think it is detecting the CMD.

```
CGEventRef event1, event2, event3, event4;
    event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)55, true); // CMD
    event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)9, true); // v
    event3 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)9, false); // v
    event4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)55, false); // CMD

    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event1);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event2);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event4);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the two events, but you need to apply modifiers.

```
CGEventRef event1, event2;
event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)9, true); // v
event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)9, false); // v

CGEventSetFlags(event1, (CGEventFlags) kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventSetFlags(event2, (CGEventFlags) kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);

CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event1);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event2);
```

In addition, you can `#import <HIToolbox/Events.h>`, and use `kVK_ANSI_V` instead of the magic number `9`.